# Raspberry Pi 3B+ Wifi intermittently cutting out (I think)

Tags: wifi

Recently I have turned on wifi to use my Pi as a wifi to ethernet router.  This was purely as I have pihole installed and some devices bypass pihole with hardcoded DNS (Chromecast device and Netflix on my TV).  The idea was that I would use iptables to redirect any DNS queries not sent to my pihole as my ISP supplied router doesn't allow this. I haven't quite got that working yet but that's one for another day.

The wifi is all set-up and working - mostly fine.  Occasionally (a lot today) the wifi seems to cut out intermittently.  There are multiple symptoms of this that I've listed below.

- The Sono's cuts out mid way through a track briefly and then keeps going. This might happen once or several times in a few seconds/minute
- Web browsing will sometimes hang for a bit (happens on multiple devices) and eventually will continue or you reload the page and it might work instantly or might continue to hang for a bit.  Sometimes multiple tabs will hang at once - other times it will be just one
- Streaming quality to the TV in will degrade quite a bit for a period of time randomly
- Streaming quality to phone will also degrade for a period of time randomly
- SSH session to the PI can be delayed in displaying whats typed. It does catch up after a few seconds.

Sometimes it will work without many issues for hours. Today it's having quite a few issues every few minutes.

The set-up I have is 
Devices <-Wifi-> Pi wlan0 <-> br0 <-> eth0 <-eth cable-> router <-> internet

I'm really not sure where to start in diagnosing this. Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: I'll hazard a guess: Based on the fact that your Sonos system is cutting out, I'd say that the issue is either in your router (most likely), or the power to your  location. All of these ISP-supplied routers are different, but you might be able to log in to yours, and find something like a QoS (Quality of Service) tab that may give a clue.

Comment: With WiFi do you mean your RasPi is configured as access point? Do you configure it with *hostapd*? Sonos is the sound system with its proprietary WiFi SonosNet? Its ZoneBridge is wired to the ethernet LAN?

Answer (score 1):

I will guess that your Internet service is where the problem is (not your RPi). The symptoms you've listed would seem to confirm this. There are some tests you can run. Rather than recommend one in particular (I'm not familiar with any of them), here's some resources you can peruse to find one you like & suits your situation:

[DSL Reports](http://www.dslreports.com/tools) has an array of monitoring tools. And you may find this thread on [super user](https://superuser.com/questions/491612/how-can-i-monitor-my-isps-connection-quality-over-time) helpful.

Sorry I can't be more specific, but I hope this helps.